# Architectural term for this large horizontal structure below an external window?

Tags: terminology, image-identification, architecture

What would one call the large **horizontal** structural fixture (on which the five faces are embedded)?

The image is from the Chicago Civic Opera Building, built in 1928.

> This throne-shaped 49-story skyscraper is home to the internationally
> renowned Lyric Opera of Chicago. It features Art Deco and Art Nouveau
> styling and ornamentation, musical motifs and an impressive arcade
> that runs the length of the east facade
>
> Source: [Open House Chicago](http://openhousechicago.org/sites/site/lyric-opera-of-chicago-civic-opera-house/)

[image: detail showing the bas relief on the horizontal panel]

Is there a precise, technical  architectural term for such a substantial, protruding, horizontal structure below an external window?

Note that I am not asking about the decorations on the structure, the faces, but the structure itself, which would presumably have the same name even if it were plain (if that's not the case, please do mention that in your answer).

Comment: A *molding*? Maybe a *corbel*? Doesn't look like a *frieze*, I don't think? Interesting question. I'm gonna go google.

Comment: A decent view [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Civic_Opera_Building_Chicago.jpg). Are they comedy/tragedy theatre masks? They look like they have more emotions than just the two...

Comment: You're not actually asking about the faces, though. It looks like you're asking about the balcony-like structure. It would help to know what it looks like from above, and what size it is -- perhaps it really is a balcony.

Comment: @AndrewLeach There are no doors above it, so it's not a balcony, but you're right that it looks fairly deep (on the axis through he building, i.e. perpendicular to the windows and parallel to the ground) and substantial, so maybe it is more prominent that a simple transom or whatever. In that case, my suggestion of a *corbel* applies more to the feature supporting it, just above the latticed port, than to the horizontal structure properly. Maybe just a *ledge*?

Comment: Just **ornaments**, probably

Comment: Hi Dan - a corbel is something that juts out to hold something up. So, picture an ordinary brick/stone-block wall: you push 1 or 2 of units "out" a bit: you have made a little "ledge" - such as you could rest something (typically a beam) on: you've corbeled. {Moreover, it's indeed that *method* of "making a ledge to hold something up". *Alternately* one could - for example - drive in a stake, bolt in supports, somehow use glue, nails, whatever: those are not corbeling.} Indeed those scrolly-things "holding it up" are sort of (perhaps fake) "corbels" for the horizontal ledge-thing in question!

Comment: [Jharokha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jharokha) from Mughal architecture, might be related.

Comment: @DanBron - if you want a proper  answer I suggest you edit the question making it clear what OP is actually asking for. It looks like I was not the only user to misunderstand it. Having said that, the technical term you are after could be more properly suggested in a construction/ architectural site.

Comment: the thing to do will be to locate the architect's plans for this particular building and see how they called it, if it's labeled.

Comment: BTW everyone I just edited the question to remove the completely crap mention of "corbels" in the first sentence, which had utterly nothing to do with anything.  (In general I'm sick of "corbel" being totally misused on here, good grief!)

Comment: @JoeBlow - why do you insist on asking this question on ELU???? This is not the place for it...ask on sites for architects or, better still, art historians.

Answer (score 12):

> What would one call the large horizontal structural fixture [...] specifically the component between the two corbels?

The most appropriate term I found, and one which matches the description and the image posted by the OP is

### balconet / balconette

[image: Civic Opera House facade]

> If we look at the definition of corbel we find:
>
> [image]
>
> *corbel*: A masonry block projecting from a wall **to support a superincumbent element**.

Technically, the central structure featured in the OP's question, is a “superincumbent element”. It also resembles a balcony owing to the presence of the corbels; however, the central protruding section is extremely narrow and the  wall particularly low, which suggest that it is only a decorative element of the façade with no practical function or use. The question arises whether it is actually deep enough for a person to stand. Moreover, the “adornment” does not appear to be an extension of the double-hung windows, which  would rule out the answers; *sill* suggested by @Phil Sweet, and the stronger contender (in my opinion) *apron* (now deleted) given  by @Joe Blow.

I propose the following: **balconet** or **balconette**

From  *Sturgis' Illustrated Dictionary of Architecture and Building* (1901-02)

> <sup>**BALCONET; [BALCONETTE](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=j9wAW2YleywC&pg=PA185&dq=Sturgis%27%20balconette&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi07MvhnaLNAhXlJ5oKHUHmAHoQ6AEINDAA#v=onepage&q=Sturgis'%20balconette&f=false)**</sup>
>
> A railing or balustrade at the outer plane of a window reaching to the floor, and having, when the window is wide open, **the appearance** of a balcony.

From Volume III the following term, **[parapet](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xEHuWo-M6WEC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=Sturgis%27%20parapet&source=bl&ots=coHb2VG6Gp&sig=liDC9gBsbQJnx8iQm7uMt_YPVBI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy5O7ur6LNAhVsSZoKHalPCvgQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Sturgis'%20parapet&f=false)**, as defined below could also be taken into consideration.

[image]

> Cont'd.
>   of the first to be emphasized by panelling and tracery, often peierced with great richness and delicacy of detail ...

---

Because images speak louder than words.

**Why that structure cannot be a sill nor an apron**

> ... stone window sills are an excellent choice for **supporting, decorating, and accenting window frames.** […] Stone window sills are very strong, **help support the entire window frame**, and are long-lasting. 
>   […] 
>   **Exterior window sills** are exposed to rain and airborne contaminant particulates. They also are in direct contact with temperature and pressure fluctuations.

[image]

Source: [Windowsills.com](http://www.windowsills.com/window-sills-2/best-natural-stone-window-sills-for-outdoor-projects/)

For more diagrams and illustrations of window frames, sills etc. I found these two sites the most helpful

1. https://ask-a-saint.silversaints.com/posts/830528-sash-cord-replacement
2. https://bloomington.in.gov/media/media/image/jpeg/6995.jpg

Comment: FWIW, there is no door out to the structure, so while whether one *could* or not is open to debate, one is not *intended* to stand on the structure. A point in favor of your answer.

Comment: I find it even more confusing. I was reprimanded for posting an answer that described the "ornaments" of the facade, now it appears it is just hat they are looking for. If the question is on the solid external decorated geometric part it still is " motif". It is typical of the deco period to provide walls with (solid) geometric figures. I agree it looks like a parapet, but it is not. – Josh61 1 hour ago

Comment: @DanBron - no, it was not you. My point is that here"the solid geometric canvas" is part of the motif, the Art Deco style made extensive  use of solid geometrical figures, it was one of its main decorative features.

Comment: @Josh61 Hmm, if that's true (and I'm not sure it is, but you probably know better than I do), then I feel it is not specific enough to this particular type of structure (at least not for my purposes).

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, I certainly imagine so! Hence my bounty!

Comment: @Josh61 I saw your answer and wish you hadn't deleted it. It provided some good leads, but missed the target IMO. DanBron is pointing out why. These bits are constituents of the motif.  I used *motif* in many of my search strings trying to find an exact term for them.

Comment: Why isn't it an apron?

Comment: @Mazura well for quite some time I thought it was, or that it was the closest answer. But I could never find deep, wide, large (window) aprons that had any sculpture or motifs.Or aprons that protruded externally, they tend to lie flat against the wall. Ironically Phil Sweet's [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331118/architectural-term-for-the-embellished-section-below-an-external-window/332206?noredirect=1#comment758350_331177) explains it quite well. I see he's updated it too, but as far as I can recall they're the same observations.

Comment: Note, I believe the final image means little or nothing.  It's simply explaining the (everyday, well-known) uses of those words in ordinary domestic window-making.  The use of such terms doesn't really relate to how they are used in "classical architecture terminology", I'd say.

Comment: hey Josh, "If that piece granite has a very specific noun, it must be a very technical one".  Well it's a **bossage**.  It's also "a stone".

Comment: I didn't see, until I edited his post and actually brought in the "clear picture" he talked about but never included, that the blank spaces above the corbels is framed such that those "empty spaces" are actually intended to suggest columns. And the corbels are "holding them up". And the actual "entablature", the semicircular cap, along with the "negative space columns" and *the plinth or pediment below them* combine to create a single, imposing, "grand entryway". So whatever the word is for the horizontal, stone, foot at the bottom of a Greek entryway is, that's the word we need.

Comment: I think you have an opportunity here. The "pediment" is the semicircular cap (I was confused on this point because from "ped" I assumed it would be low, by the *feet*). A "plinth" is just the bottom of a column. But what the plinths *rest* on -- ah, that's what we need. You could have a colonnade of 16 columns, with 16 plinths, but all those plinths would be resting on the same .... XXXX .

Comment: Definitely not a *pediment*, think of the Parthenon, I've done my research on this :) Icy's answer has merit but it's ultimately confusing. I'm being really honest here, and impartial. EDIT. steps??

Comment: Yeah, I know that now. I was just confused because the answer was hairy and I got mixed up. What do all the numberless *plinths* of the Parthenon rest on? When you walk up the grand staircase, and are standing on a huge slab of marble, before you enter the temple proper ... what are you standing on?

Comment: Yeah, I just found *stylobate* too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylobate . I think we have a winner. It's an *ornamental stylobate* supporting a modern interpretation of the classic *colonnade* using negative space (or something to that effect).  Update your answer, credit to @ICy for figuring out that the whole thing was a *colonnade* (obvious when viewed from the front & further away), but suggest that a *entablature* goes at the *top* of a colonnade, whereas the plinths traditionally rest on the *stylobate*.

Comment: stylobates are ... wait for it ..... the base of some columns.  that would be because "bates" is the English word:  "base".  "stylos" is obviously "columns".  a "sylobate" just means "base".... particularly of columns. Contemporary stonemasons use it all the time just to mean "base" or "big piece of stone shit sits on".

Comment: @DanBron - as a reference look at the 1st photo in Icy's answer.  Notice the **twelve** "square column like objects" (they each have a sort of ball or crown on the top). Are you saying you see those as a (let's say) "suggested colonade"? And then, you see the OP object as "a colonnade base"? (I'm just going to say "colonnade base" rather than "stylobate"!)  That just doesn't make a lot of sense dude. IF you see the "suggested colonade", the stylobate would be a HUGE element, as wide as that image (call it 30 meters) and imagine it say 3x as high as one of the decorative sills under discussion.

Comment: @JoeBlow The central portion of the colonnade, the tallest bit, the portico, is flanked by two "negative columns". These negative columns are standing on something. Columns are know to stand on stylobates. I get what you're saying that the stylobate might have to run the entire colonnade, but unless you can find an architectural term for the "floor of the portico" or "the portion of the stylobate within the bounds of the portico", I think *stylobate* is the best we can do.

Comment: So (A) it's really whacky that you see that (look at the first picture in Icy's) as a *suggested colonnade*, and even if we take that as a given, (B) confusing one of those things-under-discussion with a stylobate, would be a scale of errors somewhat like confusing a window with a roof, if you see what I mean.

Comment: it's an incredible stretch man. ***Maybe*** the following sentence could appear in Architectural Art Language:  *"The four story windows, from a distance out of focus, can be seen as a kind of colonnade {excitingly, with nothing on top - no pediment,  no roof, nothing - but stick with us on this}, and then if you take all the large decorative sills together from a distance {ignore the huge round windows below them} as a kind of unit, you get a sort of dotted-line stylobate."*  I mean - I don't know.  Note: **EVEN IF** we agree with this theory ("The architect was using X's to suggest ....

Comment: **EVEN IF WE AGREE WITH THIS THEORY:** *"The architect was using X's to suggest from a distance a stylobate"*.  Say we DO AGREE with that theory.  It's just nonsensical to say the answer to the question is "stylobate".  Example: the "windows" form the putative suggested-colonnade, right?  If someone was asking "What are these things called?" (one of the windows), it would be madness to answer "oh, that's a colonnade".  Of course, it's a freaking window!!!  Similarly "what is the large decorative sill called?" You can't say "stylobate" -  whaaa!!

Comment: Example, consider the window-installer guys at work installing the windows; it's humorous to think of them referring to them as "the columns". ("I just smashed a column"  "this column is smudged!" etc!)  Similarly when working on the large decorative sills, the stonemasons would not be saying "let's get the stylobate finished, guys".  That's how I see it, anyways ...  :O

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41306/discussion-on-answer-by-mari-lou-a-architectural-term-for-this-large-horizontal).

Comment: @Mari-LouA go sign up for the moderator voting !

Answer (score 6):

The building in question is the home of the Lyric Opera of Chicago built in 1929.  The Art Institute of Chicago has the clearest photo I have seen of the west exposure, as built.

[image: West exposure Civic Opera Building]

Identifying the architectural styles employed will allow us to focus the search for the name of the specific decoration. In pursuit of that, I turned to *[The History of the Civic Opera House](https://www.lyricopera.org/about/history/civicoperahistory)*, which has this to say:

> The decorative character of the entire building is a **hybrid of Art Nouveau and Art Deco styles**. Comedy-tragedy masks and cornucopia of instruments abound as playful ornaments around entrances, inspired by the Paris Opera House designed by Jean-Louis-Charles Garnier.

There is also full discussion of the building's history at *[The City of Chicago Landmark Designation Report](https://archive.org/stream/CityOfChicagoLandmarkDesignationReports/CivicOperaBuilding#page/n0/mode/2up)*, which contains description of the ornamental style employed by chief designer Alfred Shaw at page 12:

> The designer, Alfred Shaw, "... had an appreciation for the classical, Shaw sought to bring a modern interpretation to its use in contemporary design"

And further examination of the Landmark document pages 6-7 and 11-14 seems to support the idea of a modern interpretation of a classical theme.

Given this, I believe the element is a modern interpretation or expression of the classic *entablature*. The masks in its face are *frieze elements*.

From the [Columbia Electronic Encyclopedia](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/entablature)™ (2013, Columbia University Press), for example:

> #### Entablature
>
> *ĕntăb`ləcho͝or*
>   The **entire unit of horizontal members above the columns or pilasters** in classical architecture—Greek, Roman or Renaissance.
>
> The height of the entablature in relation to the column supporting it varies with **the three orders**, Doric, Ionic, and Corinthian, but in Roman and Renaissance interpretations it is generally about one fourth the column height.
>
> The entablature's component members are the architrave, which rests directly upon the abacus, or top member of the column cap; the frieze; and the cornice, or topmost member.
>
> Essentially the entablature is **a development from the primitive lintel**, which spans two posts and supports the ends of the roof rafters.
>
> In Renaissance and **modern designs the entablature is also used upon a wall as the crowning member or as a horizontal band, irrespective of columns**.

But I think we can get even more specific than this. If one examines the photos at the Lyric Opera site as well as page 9 of the Landmark Designation report, there is a *pediment* that has been removed several storeys above what I have called the *entablature*.

This would make the structure in question a stylized ***[plinth](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plinth)*** using the *[order](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/order)*¹ of an ***[entablature](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/entablature)***. This is supported by scrolled *corbels* (as had been noted in an [earlier answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/332206/revisions)) starting about six storeys above the river. The columns are more suggested by decoration than relief or structure.

Removal of the pediment strands the 'plinth' in many respects, which bears examination in its unified (and original) context which is the whole west wall, rather than singled out and stranded.

From p174 of *[Architecture for Community and Spectacle: The Roofed Arena in North America, 1853-1968](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1101&context=library_papers)*:

> ...Wall expanses were treated as decorative fields, not embellished but set off as planar surfaces against zones of focused ornament, as was done, for example, on the river face of the Civic Opera Building in Chicago (Graham, Anderson, Probst & White, 1929).

---

¹ <sub>[*Order* definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/order): *19. Architecture a. Any of several styles of classical architecture characterized by the type of column and entablature employed. Of the five generally accepted classical orders, the Doric, Ionic, and Corinthian orders are Greek and the Tuscan and Composite orders are Roman.*</sub>

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this too, but even the modern definition has it as the *crowning* member, i.e. *above* something important. As the important part of a table (entablature) is its top surface. By contrast, that sill, or whatever, is below the window.

Comment: I am probably depending (excessively?) on  "...upon a wall [...] as a horizontal band..."

Comment: Yeah, what I'm saying is this thing could 100% legitimately be called a entablature, being a horizontal band on a wall, *if it were above* the window, i.e. as a *crowning* member.

Comment: There is a pediment that has been removed which "strands" the element in question. See the added information in my answer.

Comment: "If one examines the photos at the Lyric Opera site as well as page 9 of the Landmark Designation report there is a pediment that has been removed several storeys above what I have called the entablature. This would make the structure in question a stylized* plinth using the order of an entablature." +1 for plinth, and finding that document, which I missed. The long shot of the original facade does suggest a complete portico, and *hanging plinth* is an accepted term.

Comment: an entablature???????  on what columns?

Comment: The first line of my answer I opine "a modern interpretation/extraction of an entablature" further supported by the highlighted text in the block quote. With my discovery of the Landmark document, linked above, I modified my answer to "a plinth using the order of an entablature" both terms defined.  Further examination of the Landmark document pages 6-7 and 11-14 seems to support the idea of a modern interpretation of a classical theme.  The designer, Alfred Shaw, "... had an appreciation for the classical, Shaw sought to bring a modern interpretation to its use in contemporary design." (p7)

Comment: I like all this information, it's very specific to the question at hand. But can you try to weave it all into a single, cohesive, narrative, and clearly indicate the term or terms you ultimately think answers the question?

Comment: I think this is a little clearer now

Comment: @Icy Definitely better. If you don't mind, later today, I'll take a whack at some formatting (not content) upgrades.

Comment: @Icy Ok, I made my edit. I did my best to just adjust formatting and cohesion (through adding prosaic glue), without putting words in  your mouth (to the best of my ability). I think a problem I originally had with the answer is the way you were citing things, with great formality, caused the references to swamp the text. Please feel free to edit to taste or rollback completely. Also see [this comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331118/architectural-term-for-this-large-horizontal-structure-below-an-external-window#comment759503_331118) I made under the question.

Comment: I'm happy enough with this, thank you.  I only had enough time this AM to do the basic reorder and to make sure the links still worked.  Formatting is a bit of a challenge for me.  I am guessing that we have moved a long way off-topic but this was fun.

Comment: So, in as much as the windows are an architectural suggestion of columns, the windows are called: "windows".  If there's an idea that the decorative sills / round windows, taken together, are an architectural suggestion of a plinth or stylobate, fine. What is the name for the decorative sills?

Comment: @JoeBlow No, as I said initially and still maintain, an *entablature* must be a *crowning* member. If there is one, it is up there with the semicircular pediment. I awarded the bounty to Icy because his research and scholarship were exemplary, and led me to see the horizontal structure in a larger context, and now it's clear to me the ornament is in question is intended to suggest the foot of a portico, surrounded by a colonnade. I hadn't seen that before Icy pointed it out. And that clue now opens fruitful new avenues: *stylobate* and such.

Answer (score 5):

**[Sill](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sill)** should do, unless there is something specific to opera houses.

> - A shelf or slab of stone, wood, or metal at the foot of a window or
>     doorway. A strong horizontal member at the base of any structure,
>     e.g., in the frame of a motor or rail vehicle.

ODO

Comment: Nice. Glad you included that definition, because now I know *sills* can refer to more than just the unimpressive little surfaces cats sit on.

Comment: In a sense it is a sill, **but** it's entirely possible that any - uh - neoclassical architecture philologists reading, would laugh at us, and assert that (for example) "a giant decorative sill-like structure below an arcade of windows is of course known as a blah-blah"

Comment: Similarly, if I'm not mistaken they are a kind of **bossage**, you could say.

Comment: @JoeBlow yes, I half expected that to happen. I originally expressed some doubt about the answer, but edited it when it held up for an hour.

Comment: I am positive that the term *sill* is incorrect, I checked many sources, and references before looking elsewhere, and *balconet* comes close. The aforementioned structure protrudes externally, it is not internal, and there are no moldings. See the following: diagram http://thumbsnap.com/s/oFXz2lpt.jpg

Comment: I think the sill is on the inside of the window, not the outside. But maybe it can be either.

Comment: I will try to post a more thorough answer in the future. I have company arriving soon from overseas and may not have time to put a solid answer together for a while. It is difficult to explain rationale in a stand alone answer when much of it has to do with why several other proposed terms don't apply, and basically that leaves you with this unsatisfying, but serviceable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Previous suggestions have been good. I would add (back) [apron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apron_(architecture)): "a raised section of ornamental stonework below a window ledge, stone tablet, or monument."

"Cornice," "lintel," and "[pop-out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KixOMgLt89o)" are also worth considering. Also, in French, it would be called a "tablette d'appui."

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal decorated structure   you see on the facade is an  ***architectonic [motif](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motif)***. In this specific case it is one of the  Art Deco  architectonic motifs which are often  characterized by emphasised geometric forms as suggested in the following extract:

> - ***Deco emphasizes geometric forms: spheres, polygons, rectangles, trapezoids, zigzags, chevrons, and sunburst motifs.***  Elements are often arranged in symmetrical patterns.
> - ***By the 1930s the style had become much more flamboyant, and added much more decoration on the facade***. It was particularly popular for movie theaters, such as the Grand Rex in Paris (1932), and Radio City Music Hall in New York City; and in the decoration of skyscrapers. (wikipedia)

The fact that they look like a sill, a balconette or a parapet for instance, is part of a geometrical optical effects typical of Art Deco.

***Architectonic motif:***

> - A repeated figure or design in architecture or decoration. (M-W)

***[Frieze](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/frieze)*** is another term:

> - any decorative band on an outside wall, broader than a stringcourse and bearing lettering, sculpture, etc.

Here are other examples: [image]

[image]

P.S. I don't know if there is a technical term for these "motifs", but they are generally referred to also as elements or figures.

Comment: Say Josh I think the OP is asking about the "large thing" which the motifs are ON.  (boss, balcony, slab of granite, whatever the heck it's called!)

Comment: @JoeBlow -in this case this is "unclear what you are asking" at best.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -      What I mean is that Art Deco made extensive use of these geometric optical effects imitating what at first sight appeared as a balconette, parapet etc. but the intent was exclusively decorative, with no real function.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. The entire structural piece is, according to you, a motif because it is merely ornamental. It's one way of interpreting  the solid three dimensional element. But I disagree with your analysis; motifs, are used to beautify elements that would otherwise be plain. If the horizontal protruding structure on the Opera Civic Building had been totally plain, would you still call that a motif? Art Deco motif describes  the *style* and *era / period*. Like *impressionism*, *cubism*, or *futurism*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - according to the Art Deco aesthetic e three dimensional geometric figure is a "motif".

Comment: @Mari-LouA look at the first picture, what would you call the part where the with  human figures are attached ? A balconette, an apron, a sill...? It is just a solid  geometric architectonic element typical of that style. What I don't know is the technical term, it there is one.

Comment: None of the above, they are still low-relief sculptures "stuck on" to beautify the facade. Note the absence of corbels. Sills can have corbels, but they are flourishing touches; balconies, balconets will either have corbels or brackets to support their weight. None of your images have brackets or corbels. We could go on discussing about this for hours. I don't *dislike* your answer. But I really dislike *sill*, and that's why I felt compelled to post my solution.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Sill is wrong because it doesn't  event look like a sill, but it is not a balconette of a parapet.

Comment: btw I think "bossage" is a word you may be looking for in this discussion.