# What is this architectural element called?

Tags: single-word-requests, architecture

In the image below there is a rectangular roof above the entrance, which sits on four columns.

[image: Hotel Métropole]

What is it called?

My guess: [Apron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apron_(architecture))

Comment: We call it the **overhang** when it's a smaller structure like a house. I guess it's called the same.

Comment: On the theme of architecture, the following question might be of interest: [Architectural term for this large horizontal structure below an external window?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331118/architectural-term-for-this-large-horizontal-structure-below-an-external-window)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an example of a [*portico*](http://buffaloah.com/a/DCTNRY/p/port.html):

> A roofed entrance porch supported on at least one side by columns
>
> Classical Greek architeture: A portico was the principal porch or
>   entrance to a Greek temple, and was roofed and usually open at the
>   sides. The number of columns that made up a portico determined its
>   architectural name. For example, tetrastyle (four columns), hexastyle
>   (six columns), octastyle (eight columns), decastyle (ten columns).

So the picture specifically depicts a *tetrastyle portico*.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose *portico* may be the best word for the feature in your question. 
But a closely related word is ***marquee***:

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marquee):
>
>   a permanent canopy often of metal and glass
>     projecting over an entrance (as of a hotel or theater)
>   - The hotel doorman was stationed under the *marquee.*
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=marquee):
>
>   A rooflike structure, often bearing a signboard,
>     projecting over an entrance, as to a theater or hotel.

I concede that a marquee is typically constructed as a [cantilever](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=cantilever);
i.e., not supported by columns.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if there is a formal word for the roof part of a portico but the decorative bit around the edge is a [cornice or frieze](http://www.adrianarchitecture.org/glossary/#cornices)